# Fedora lower vesion not allowing php upgrade

Tags: linux, upgrade, fedora, php

I have php 5.2.9 installed on fedora6. Now I want to upgrade php on it's latest version. But lower version of fedora not allowing

I tried with yum and rpm commands.

Please help me how can I upgrade PHP ?

Comment: Please include the exact commands you used and the error messages you received.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 6 has been end-of-life for a long time. It's no longer maintained, and new packages aren't being released for it. You have two options: 1) upgrade to a recent version of Fedora or 2) compile upstream PHP source yourself. I strongly recommend staying away from #2 unless you want to dive into the rabbit hole.

Comment: can I run 2 fedora installation on one system as we can do with windows ? because I don't want to do anything with existing.

Comment: If you have available disk space, yes you can create a new partition (or set thereof) and install a new version of Fedora. You'll need to figure out how to dual-boot that system on your own, as it will be dependent on the location of the existing installation.